# Is there an inverted version of numpy.all()?

Tags: python, numpy

As stated in the [docs for `numpy.all()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

> `numpy.all()` tests whether all array elements along a given axis **evaluate to True**.

Is there a function, that does the opposite: Check whether all array elements along a given axis (I need the diagonal) **evaluates to False**.

What I need in particular is to check if the diagonal of a 2-dimensional matrix is **zero every where**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, to extract the diagonal, you can use `mymatrix.diagonal()`.

There are quite a few ways to do what you want.

To test whether it is zero everywhere you can do `numpy.all(mymatrix.diagonal() == 0)`.

Alternatively, "everything is equal to zero (False)" is the same as "nothing equal to True", so you could also use `not numpy.any(mymatrix.diagonal())`.

Since it's a numeric matrix though, you can just add up the absolute value of the elements on the diagonal and if they're all 0, each element must be zero: `numpy.sum(numpy.abs(mymatrix.diagonal()))==0`.

Answer (score 1):

the boolean condition can be anything. so either

```
(np.diag(x) == 0).all()
```

or

```
(np.diag(x) != 0).any()
```

works, but the second version stops early on the any check if there is a false case. Both cases need to build the full boolean array.